# British terms for shopping mall, shopping complex and shopping centre

Tags: american-english, british-english

Is there any differences between shopping mall, shopping centre and shopping complex? Which term is more commonly used for British speakers?

Comment: @mick Mutual scratching back society.

Comment: @PeterPoint Just sayin' ... and may I respectfully point out that I haven't up-voted.

Comment: @mick Ah, you're a huntin', shootin', fishin' kinda-of-guy.

Comment: @mick  In that case, may I tender my resignation forthwith and seek my own self-scratching-back society!

Answer (score 1):

They are all understandable by Brits and there is no difference in meaning that I am aware of, but *shopping centre* is definitely the most usual. *Shopping mall* is a little too transatlantic for some people's tastes, but as you will see from the following chart, it is rapidly gaining ground.

[image]

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shopping+centre%2Cshopping+mall%2Cshopping+complex&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshopping%20centre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshopping%20mall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshopping%20complex%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Transatlantic becomes trans-orient where I'm living. Here we have emporiums by the truckload!

Comment: *emporia surely?

Comment: For me there is a difference between a Shopping Centre and a Shopping Mall. I would expect a Shopping Mall to be enclosed, and probably multi-storey whereas a Shopping Centre is more likely to be open to the elements. A Shopping Complex could be either, or have elements of both, and be larger than a Shopping Centre. However all of them would be single developments rather than a stretch of organically developed High Street.

Comment: You're right - and malls are becoming more and more commonplace.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Quite so! Euphoria at Bangkok's emporia - the way to go!